# Como eliminar elementos de un array de objetos en java

Tags: java

el problema que estoy teniendo es el siguiente: Estoy modelando un equipo de *basketball* con algunas funciones como `agaregarTitular()` y `agregarSuplente()`. Ahora quiero implementar el método `cambiarSuplenteComoTitular()`, para ello me definí 2 arreglos del tipo `Jugador`; uno de suplentes y otro de titulares pero, una vez que hago el cambio, necesito eliminar al jugador que cambie del arreglo de suplentes; pero no se como  hacerlo.

```
public class Equipo{

private String nombre;
private int a=0;
private int b=0;    
Jugador cambio;
private Jugador titulares[];
private Jugador suplentes[];

public Equipo(String nombre, int ntitulares, int nsuplentes){
    this.nombre=nombre;
    try{
    if(ntitulares+nsuplentes==30){
    titulares=new Jugador[ntitulares];
    suplentes=new Jugador[nsuplentes];
    }}
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
    System.out.println("Error 0");
    }
}

public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

public void dimeNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre=nombre;
}

public void agregarTitular(Jugador j){
    for(int i=0;i<titulares.length;i++){
        if(titulares[i]==null){
            titulares[i]=j;
        }
    }
}

public void agregarSuplente(Jugador j){
    for(int i=0;i<suplentes.length;i++){
        if(suplentes[i]==null){
            suplentes[i]=j;
        }
    }
}

public boolean cambiarSuplenteComoTitular(long ncedula){
    boolean traspaso=false;
    for(int i=0;i<suplentes.length;i++){
        if(suplentes[i].getCedula()==ncedula){
                cambio=suplentes[i];
                    agregarTitular(cambio);
                    traspaso=true;
                }else{
                    traspaso=false;
                }
            }



    return traspaso;
}
```

Comment: Quizas esto te puedas servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112503/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, veo que la *firma* de tu método de `cambiarSuplenteComoTitular` está incompleta, pues solo recibe un `ncedula`, y viendo solo el nombre del parámetro no me queda claro si es el del suplente o del titular. Además el nombre del método me choca un poco, pues se sobre-entiende que un *cambio* en *basketball* siempre es de un suplente por un titular.

Dado que veo entonces, un típico caso del [problema x y](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/21), responderé lo que no estás preguntando:

Sugiero un cambio en la firma del método por algo como:

```
public bool realizarCambio(long nCedulaSuplente, long nCedulaTitular)
```

Entonces, la implementación, básicamente tiene que identificar a cada `Jugador` en su arreglo e intercambiarlos, sin *eliminar* nada de ningún arreglo, pues la cantidad de jugadores permanece constante, digamos, algo como esto:

```
public bool realizarCambio(long nCedulaSuplente, long nCedulaTitular) {
  bool result = false;
  int idxSuplente, idxTitular;
  Jugador titular, suplente;
  //buscamos primero al suplente
  for (int i=0; i<suplentes.length; i++) {
    if (suplentes[i].getCedula() == nCedulaSuplente) {
      suplente = suplentes[i];
      idxSuplente = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  //buscamos ahora al titular
  for (int i=0; i<titulares.length; i++) {
    if (titulares[i].getCedula() == nCedulaTitular) {
      titular = titulares[i];
      idxTitular = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  //si encontramos a ambos
  if (suplente != null && titular != null) {
    //simplemente los intercambiamos en los arreglos
    titulares[idxTitular] = suplente;
    suplentes[idxSuplente] = titular;
    result = true;
  } 
  return result;
}
```

Es probable que el código tenga algún error, lo he escrito aquí mismo en el editor de StackOverflow, es para dar una idea, que lo comprendas y hagas tu propia implementación.

Answer (score 1):

En java tienes ArrayUtils  el cual puedes usar para eliminar un item de  un array conociendo el índice .

Te dejo información aquí : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#remove%28java.lang.Object[],%20int%29

Siguiendo el material, quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
public boolean cambiarSuplenteComoTitular(long ncedula){
    boolean traspaso=false;
    for(int i=0;i<suplentes.length;i++){
        if(suplentes[i].getCedula()==ncedula){
                cambio=suplentes[i];
                    agregarTitular(cambio);
                    ArrayUtils.remove(suplentes,i); // Elimino Suplente
                    traspaso=true;
                }else{
                    traspaso=false;
                }
            }
    return traspaso;
}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: aunque este enlace puede ayudar a responder, se pide que la información relevante del mismo vaya aqui, dale editar por que así como esta ahorita es de baja calidad

Comment: esta respuesta no parece ser acuerda, la misma documentacion de [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#remove%28java.lang.Object[],%20int%29) "This method returns a new array with the same elements..." osea  `ArrayUtils.remove(suplentes,i); ` no cambia el array puesto suplentes sigue apuntando a la referencia anterior no al "nuevo array" ademas al usar `ArrayUtils.remove` retorna un array con menos campos. y a lo que me da a entender el texto completo lo que se desea es removerlo del array no modificar el Array

Answer (score 1):

te paso un ejemplo en java 8 de como podes eliminar un objecto en un array de objectos:

```
suplentes = Arrays.stream(suplentes).filter(j -> j.getCedula()!= ncedula).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Jugador[0]);
```

Básicamente filtra por el número de cédula que recibe como parámetro y asigna la nueva lista a la lista de objectos ya existente. Espero que te sirva !
Saludos.